# posting to my Laravel website from another website and getting 302 error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a core PHP website and from there I am trying to post data to my laravel site but getting a 302

my php form

```
<form name="frm_payInternational" action="https://abcd.com/international" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value="">
                <div style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                    <input name="paymentInterEmail" id="paymentInterEmail" placeholder="Enter Email Id" style="width:400px;height:30px;border-radius:5px;" >
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                    <input name="paymentInterAmt" id="paymentInterAmt" placeholder="Enter Amount" style="width:400px;height:30px;border-radius:5px;" >
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                    <button type="submit" name="btn_makePaymentInter" id="btn_makePaymentInter" class="btn">Make Payment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

my routes.php code

```
// Payment Link
Route::post('/international', 'PurchaseController@paymentLink');
```

Comment: 302 is not an error but a redirect. Where does it try to redirect you to? And: a lot of sites do a redirect-after-post to avoid the hassle of browsers asking users if they want to re-post their values on history navigation.

Comment: It redirects me back to the same page from where I am posting this form .. I am guessing it needs a csrf_token but don't know how to pass it

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add the route in VerifyCsrfToekn.php middleware

```
protected $except = [
        "route_name"
    ];
```

This is not ideal but just wanted a quick fix for the time being

Comment: No don't do this. What this does is, it skips checking the csrf token for this route and you don't want that. Add `{{  csrf_field() }}` anywhere in the `<form>` element.

Comment: But the other website is not on Laravel

Comment: Ah okay, if so then what you did was correct. [More info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)